# Surjective function - proving

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functions

$f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$

$f(x) = x^3 -2x^4$

In order to prove that $f$ is not surjective, my teacher told me to find that in most the $f$ is negative.
And indeed, only for $0<x<0.5$ it's positive. But how it helps me to understand it's not surjective?

Comment: Can you find a point where the function has a maximum? If so, then it can't be surjective (on this range).

Comment: Maybe show that any positive value of the function is less than $(0.5)^3$.

Comment: *Surjective* means that for any point *b* in the codomain, you can find a point *a* in the domain such that $$f(a) = b$$. If you can't "get to" certain (positive values), then the function is not surjective.

Comment: Draw the function.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is continuous and only non-negative on the interval $[0,0.5]$. Thus the function must take a maximum value on this interval (since it's continuous and the interval is closed), and so any positive value greater than the maximum is not achieved by your function so your function is not surjective.

Comment: so surjective function is only positive/negative for any x?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right: for $0<x<\frac{1}{2}$ $f(x)$ is positive. But for $x \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ you have:

$$x^3-2x^4=x^3(1-2x)<\frac{1}{2^3}(1-2x)$$

It's because $f(x)$ is positive and $0<x<\frac{1}{2}$. Next:

$$\frac{1}{2^3}(1-2x)<\frac{1}{2^3}$$

Because for $0<x<\frac{1}{2}$ you have $0<1-2x<1$. So $f$ reach values less than $\frac{1}{2^3}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, because for $x<0$ or $x>\frac{1}{2}$ it's negative. So, for example, $f$ doesn't reach value $2$.

Answer (score 0):

If the function is only positive in $[0, 0.5]$, and it's continuous, it must have a maximum there. Hence, any value greater than this maximum is not $f(x)$, for any $x \in \Bbb R$. Finding this maximum is another problem, better dealt with calculus.

Comment: so surjective function is only positive/negative for any x?

Comment: No. A function $f: A \to B$ is surjective if for any $y \in B$, exists $a \in A$ such that $f(x) = y$. Meaning that everybody in $B$ gets hit by someone in $A$. If the function is positive on an interval, and negative elsewhere, there must be some value high enough that the function can't hit. That's the idea.

Comment: But therefore, a function without a max/min  -> always up/down

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "up/down".

Comment: monotonic increasing or decresing

Comment: Not necessarily. You can have something defined on a open interval, which oscilates like the $\sin$ function, for instance. Consider [this function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+0.5x++%2B+sin+x) on the interval $(0,6)$. It does not achieve global maxima or minima. And it is not monotonic.

Comment: so surjective functions can't have max/min?

Comment: It really depends on the domain and codomain of the function. For instance, $f: ]0,1[ \to ]0,1[$ given by $f(x) = x$ does not have a maximum nor minimum, since $]0,1[$ is open. But is is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the derivatives

$$ f'(x)=3x^2-8x^3 $$
$$ f''(x)=6x-24x^2 $$

So we have critical points at $x=0$ and $x=3/8$. For $x\in (-\infty,0)$ we see that $f'(-1)=3-8(-1)=11>0$ so $f(x)$ is increasing.

$f'(1)=3-8=-5<0$ so for $x\in (3/8, \infty)$ $f(x)$ is decreasing.

We also see $f''(3/8)=6(3/8)-24*(3/8)^2=9/4-9/8=18/8-27/8=-9/8<0$ which means $3/8$ is a maximum.

Since $f(0)=0$, $f(3/8) \approx .013 $, we conclude that $(3/8,f(3/8))$ is a global maximum.  So consider any point in the codomain ($\mathbb R$) greater than $f(3/8)$ (Let's take 2 for example). There is no $x\in domain(f)$ such that $f(x)= 2$. Thus $f$ is no surjective (proved by contrapositive)